# .net 4.5 Correct Windows Service Start Method

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

Now that Tasks seem to be the accepted way of implementing most multi-threading, is this now the *"correct"* way to write a windows service start method?

The start method will complete quickly but I'm new to Tasks and want to make sure that this is the correct way to implement the service work.

I've tested it and it seems to work but I want to know if there are side effects to this approach.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(() => MyServiceThingsToDo());
}

private void MyServiceThingsToDo()
{
    // all the stuff I want to do like read from database, send alerts
    // even start other tasks
}
```

I've looked around at the usual sources and can't find any source (MSDN or otherwise) that specifically states that this is the *right* way to build a service now.

Comment: Tasks (typically) use thread pool threads. Which should not be used for long-lived tasks (such as the implementation of a service). So, no...I would not say that using the Task class is the right way to implement a service. You should just create a new Thread directly.

Comment: This is highly opinion based. One thing that is noticeable immediately is exception handling.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Not necessarily. You can use `Task.Factory.StartNew` and specify `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` to explicitly require the creation of a new thread (and not a threadpool one).

Comment: It is not opinion based, BUT: it is depending on waht the service DOES. I know some services that pretty much initialize then wait for someone to call their API (which is handled by the framework, so no thread waits) - in which case OnStart is the perfect place to do it WITHOUT a separate thread. I generally handle initialization in the start method - if something blows (bad config etc.) I want start to fail so other dependent servics do not start.

Comment: @TomTom The recommended practice is to release `OnStart` as quickly as possible. You could still be waiting on an API call in a background thread.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov RTFM? It does not say so. And many services start synchroneus. When start is done, the service is supposed to be running. YXour approach is an antipattern and totally invalidates for example service dependencies when another service has to wait for this one to be STARTED (and read to answer) - and that is an OS core functionality.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: thanks...I'd forgotten about the `LongRunning` option. That said, for an operation that does not produce a result, I don't see an advantage of Task over Thread (the other big benefit of Task is representing a "future" result, which isn't of concern here).

Comment: @TomTom What i ment was that `OnStart` needs to finish in a timely fashion. You cant make it block for as long as you want waiting for a synchronous API call.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Not quite right. A `Task` is simply a higher level abstraction. it may execute a thread or it may not, depending on what it actually does. Of course you can always use the `Thread`, but with `Task` you gain more abstractions, such as `CancellationToken`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: CancellationToken is usable even without a Task. But more to the point, I am specifically addressing the question here, where the abstractions Task offers are not useful. It's _harder_ to use Task here (to get the desired behavior requires specifying additional options as compared to using Thread), so why bother?

Comment: @PeterDuniho We aren't forcing anyone, we're just pointing out things to know when deciding which to use. I dont see how using the `Task.Factory.StartNew` overload is *harder*. `CancellationToken` is usable, yes, but plays nicely along with `Task`.

Comment: @TomTom: from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx#BK_WriteCode: "The OnStart method must return to the operating system after the service's operation has begun. _It must not loop forever or block._" [emphasis mine]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this in enterprise applications and it works without issue:

```
_messageQueueWatcher = new Task(_engineService.StartMessageQueueWatcher, _cancelTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
_messageQueueWatcher.Start();
```

I run this from an asynchronous call off of OnStart(string[] args){}